# Is there any way to read a layered PDF in python

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf which is layered when trying to read the PDF file it is just reading the header of the PDF and footer of the PDF. I am looking for a library which can read the layered PDF.

Please guide.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "layered"? Can you provide the PDF? Screenshot? What do you mean by "trying to read"?

Comment: @Ryan Layered means the selectable PDF, So libraries were only reading the PDF header and footer. However, I was able to solve this issue with the "fitz" library and this is solved. Thank you.